# console.log inside loopback Rest API

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, loopback

I'm working on a react app that has a Loopback Rest API. I'm trying to create a post method that takes an array of articles as an argument. The functions are created but they doesn't work. Unfortunately i don't know how to debug and id'd like to see wether my call even enters the function and if so how the object / array looks like.

in remote-cart.js

```
Cart.addArticles = (id, articles, cb) => {

console.log(articles);

articles.map(article => {
  let error;
  if (article.qty <= 0) {
    error = new Error('Quantity can\'t be negative or null!');
    error.statusCode = 400;
    error.code = 'cant_be_negative_or_null'.toUpperCase();
    return cb(error);
  }
  Promise
    .all([Cart.findById(id), Article.findById(article.articleId)])
    .then((all) => {
      const article = all[1];
      if (!article) {
        error = new Error('Article doesn\'t exist');
        error.statusCode = 400;
        error.code = 'Article_doesnt_exist'.toUpperCase();
        cb(error);
      }
      const cart = all[0];
      let articles = [];
      if (cart.articles) {
        // articles exist
        articles = JSON.parse(cart.articles);
        const articleIndex =  _findIndex(articles, (item) =>
          item.articleId === article.id);
        if (articles[articleIndex]) {
          const oldQty = articles[articleIndex].qty ?
            articles[articleIndex].qty : 0;
          const newQty = oldQty + article.qty;
          articles[articleIndex].qty = newQty;
          
          articles[articleIndex].total = calculateSubTotal(article, newQty);
        } else {
          articles.push({
            articleId: article.articleId,
            qty: article.qty,
            total: calculateSubTotal(article, article.qty),
          });
        }
      } else {
        // articles doesn't exit
        articles.push({
          articleId: article.articleId,
          qty: article.qty,
          total: calculateSubTotal(article, article.qty),
        });
      }
      cart.articles = JSON.stringify(articles);
      cart.total = calculateTotal(articles);
      return cart;
    })
    .then(cart => {
      cart.save({}, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          return err;
        }
        cb(null, cart);
      });
    })
    .catch(err => cb(err));
});
};


Cart.remoteMethod('addArticles', {
description: [
  'Add or increase the quantity of any Article in cart',
  ' model instance by {{id}} from the data source',
],
accepts: [{
  arg: 'id',
  type: 'number',
  required: true,
}, {
  arg: 'articles',
  type: 'array',
  required: true,
}],
returns: [
  {arg: 'id', type: 'number', root: true},
  {arg: 'clientId', type: 'number', root: true},
  {arg: 'articles', type: 'string', root: true},
  {arg: 'total', type: 'number', root: true},
  {arg: 'lines', type: 'array', root: true},
  {arg: 'lineCount', type: 'number', root: true},
  {arg: 'created_at', type: 'Date', root: true},
  {arg: 'updated_at', type: 'Date', root: true},
],
http: {path: '/:id/add-articles', verb: 'post'},
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> The functions are created but they doesn't work. Unfortunately i don't know how to debug and id'd like to see wether my call even enters the function and if so how the object / array looks like.

Run your application with the environment variable `DEBUG` set to `strong-remoting:*`. That will give you insights into what's happening inside LoopBack's REST API layer.

See [Setting debug strings](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Setting-debug-strings.html) in LoopBack's documentation for more details.